# How do I write a script to output an html file?

Tags: bash, scripts, html, cat

What am I doing wrong in this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /tmp/flash-viewer.htm <<- _EOF_
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Flash Viewer</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<object width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" data=\"$1\"></object>
</BODY></HTML>
_EOF_

if [ -n $BROWSER ]; then
  $BROWSER '/tmp/flash-viewer.htm'
elif which xdg-open > /dev/null; then
  xdg-open '/tmp/flash-viewer.htm'
elif which gnome-open > /dev/null; then
  gnome-open '/tmp/flash-viewer.htm'
else
  echo "Could not detect the web browser to use."
fi
```

The script gives these errors:

```
joe@U13:~/Script$ ./html-flash-viewer.sh "/home/joe/video.swf"
/tmp/flash-viewer.htm: line 1: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Flash: command not found
/tmp/flash-viewer.htm: line 2: <object: command not found
/tmp/flash-viewer.htm: line 3: </BODY></HTML>: No such file or directory
```

Is there some kind of escape sequence I'm missing? I've already tried using \ to escape the LT/GT brackets and enclosing the html in single and double quotes. Each produces similar errors.

Comment: What does `$BROWSER` actually evaluate to? it looks like your script is trying to execute the contents of the HTML file, rather than pass it as an argument to the command.

Comment: How are you trying to execute the script? You have not set the `BROWSER` variable anywhere, when is it set?

Comment: if works for me if I launch it with `BROWSER=firefox ./your_script.sh`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `$BROWSER` is empty `[ -n $BROWSER ]` becomes just `[ -n ]`. That tests if `-n` has non-zero length, which is always true.

Then `$BROWSER '/tmp/flash-viewer.htm'` is executed which actually is just  `'/tmp/flash-viewer.htm'` if `$BROWSER` is empty.

Use

```
if [ -n "$BROWSER" ]; then
```

so that there's always a second argument.

To find out the exact path of your browser, use `which <browser>`, replacing `<browser>` with the browser you are trying to open the file with.

For example,

```
which firefox
```

would return `/usr/bin/firefox`, so you could do:

```
BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: Or you can use Bash's [double square brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870055/26428). Also, `type -p` is better than `which` (for one thing, it's a built-in).

Comment: While this answer is insightful, it does not help me. The browser selection code was taken from another question on this site and it works for me. The problem lies with the "cat" statement (aka "Here document") not writing the html tags.

Comment: According to the error messages there are errors when *running* (not writing) `/tmp/flash-viewer.htm`.

Comment: Right you are. I removed the $BROWSER section of the if statement and xdg-open launched the file. Thanks. -- I had thought $BROWSER was a global system environment variable. ...Wonder why it worked in that other guy's script.